# How can I a variable value into a sql table along with the results from a select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert the results of a SQL select statement into a table, ALONG WITH a value in a SQL variable inside of a FETCH loop.  I can do just an insert with the select results, but can't figure out how to insert the variable value along with it.

This is what I've Tried:

```
IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES')>=-1
BEGIN
 DEALLOCATE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES
END
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempIDs') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempIDs

CREATE TABLE #TempIDs(
 ID char(256)
 ,DBName char(256))

DECLARE @DB_NAME nvarchar(256);

DECLARE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM Sys.Databases
WHERE name like 'ZM_%' 

OPEN CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES

FETCH CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
--  if  OBJECT_ID(@DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist') is not null   EXEC('Insert into #TempIDs (ID) Select ID from '+ @DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist')
  if  OBJECT_ID(@DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist') is not null   EXEC('Insert into #TempIDs (ID, DBName) Select ID, @DB_NAME from '+ @DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist')
  FETCH CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES  INTO @DB_NAME
END

Select * from #TempIDs
```

I get this as a result:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
Must declare the scalar variable "@DB_NAME".
```

I've also tried with this which didn't work:

```
if  OBJECT_ID(@DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist') is not null   EXEC('Insert into #TempIDs (ID, set DBName=''' +@DB_NAME + ''') Select ID  from '+ @DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist')
  FETCH CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES  INTO @DB_NAME
```

and this which also didn't work:

```
if  OBJECT_ID(@DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist') is not null   EXEC('Insert into #TempIDs (ID, DBName=''' +@DB_NAME + ''') Select ID  from '+ @DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist')
  FETCH CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES  INTO @DB_NAME
```

Comment: Did you try to doble quote ? `Select ID from '''+ @DB_NAME + '''.dbo.Userlist'`

Comment: @Jeremy, I tried what you suggested, but that's not where I'm having the issue and it also gave an error because that's no where I was trying to use the value of (at)DB_NAME, so I tried this: 'Insert into #TempIDs (ID, DBName) Select ID, ''(at)DB_NAME'' from '+ (at)DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist'.  That didn't give an error, but it put the literal (at)DB_NAME in the column, not the value of (at)DB_NAME.  ... BTW, using (at) to represent the at symbol because stackoverflow was complaining.

Comment: Considering the original error is here `from '+ @DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist`, you did to full write the path; 'DB'.'scheme'.'table'. You are not in the same execution context when you start with dynamic SQL in a cursor. One easy way to proceed for debug is to assign the dynamic query to a var and switch with `EXEC(@query)` and `PRINT(@query)`, if you can exec the out print, then it will work in `EXEC()`

Comment: Both of your `INSERT` statements are incorrect. Instead: `'Insert into #TempIDs (ID, DBName) Select ID,  ''' + @DB_NAME + ''' from ' + @DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist'` Give that one a run and I think you'll get it.

Answer (score 0):

Answer thanks to @JNevil in comments:

Change the SQL statement.  This line was changed and it now works:

```
  if OBJECT_ID(@DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist') is not null EXEC('Insert into #TempIDs (ID, DBName) Select ID, ''' + @DB_NAME + ''' from ' + @DB_NAME + '.dbo.Userlist')
```